# setState in React doesn't update

Tags: reactjs

I need to get data from S3 by a querySnapshot from firebase which gives me the keys and then shows videos, I used setVideos to update the videos array that contains RetrivedVideo which is a class that needs id and url, my problem is that when I call setVideos it doesn't shows me the videos, can you help me please?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Video from "./Video";
import "./Home.css";
import RetrivedVideo from "./RetrivedVideo.js";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseApp from "./firebase.js";
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";

export default function Home() {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let data = [];

    const db = getFirestore();
    
    async function fetchData() {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "videos"));
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        await Storage.get(doc.id).then((signedURL) => {
          const retrivedVideo = new RetrivedVideo(doc.id, signedURL);
          data.push(retrivedVideo);
        });
      });
      setVideos([...videos, ...data]);
      console.log(videos);
    }
    fetchData();
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container-videos">
      {videos.map((v) => (
          <Video
            className="video"
            key={v.id}
            url={v.url}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your setVideos will fire before the data is loaded, because you're not awaiting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the state before the data is loaded. Another error is that you're using the spread operator wrong, it should be within an array `[...myArr, ...mySecArr]`

Try moving the `setVideos` within your fetchData function

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let data = [];

    const db = getFirestore();
    
    async function fetchData() {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "videos"));
      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const signedUrl = await Storage.get(doc.id);
        const retrivedVideo = new RetrivedVideo(doc.id, signedURL);
        data.push(retrivedVideo);
      });
      setVideos([...videos, ...data]);
    }
    fetchData();
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: I updated the code like this but still doesn't work, if I see the vector with a console.log(data) I can see my elements inside it but if I see videos I can't see the updated state and it's still empty

Answer (score 0):

You are using `setVideos` wrong way. Please update it and move it inside end of `fetchData`:

```
async function fetchData() {
  ...
  setVideos([...videos, ...data]);
}
fetchData()
```

Answer (score 0):

try rendering like this

```
return (
          <div className="app">
              <div className="container-videos">
                  {
                     (videos) ? videos.map((v) => (
                         <Video
                             className="video"
                             key={v.id}
                             url={v.url}
                          />
                        ))
                        : ''
                    }
                </div>
             </div>
         );
```